# Jewish life during the times of the Black Death

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, medicine, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, lifespans

I'm looking for any sources (if possible maybe even first-hand written accounts) of how Jews who lived in Western Europe at that time handled this particular period.

Anything goes, matter of fact description of cases by Jewish doctors (in the manner of Albert Camus' novel 'The Plague') or religious reconciliations by Rabbis. I want to learn a bit more about that.

(Granted, the current lockdown somewhat kindled my interest in those topics)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.bh.org.il/blog-items/700-years-before-coronavirus-jewish-life-during-the-black-death-plague/

Comment: As this stands, it seems to be too broad and also off-topic as Jews not Judaism. Maybe you can [edit] to narrow in on "religious reconciliations by Rabbis," which would address both concerns?